# How to block in Nginx requests with no referral

Tags: nginx

I have a site that is used with no permission by someone inside an mobile app , because i have noticed an big increase in direct android users with no referrals.
I have tried to block access to the directory like this :

```
location /widget/link/ {  if ($http_referer = "") {  return 403; } }
```

but i have noticed that the API dosent work for the rest of the visitors with referral because they get 404 , with this error in the logs

```
2019/08/11 12:22:27 [error] 1914#1914: *2417 "/home/site/public/widget/link/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 2.44.127.232, server: domain.com, request: "GET /widget/link/?link=https://example.com
```

i want to protect against someone else using my site inside an mobile APP
how do i block all Chrome Mobile users with no referral to /widget/link/ ?

my nginx conf is here

```
        server_name domain.com;
        root /home/domain/public/;
index index.html index.htm index.php;


  location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                 fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;



   }
  location ~ ^/(assets|images|javascripts|stylesheets|system)/ {
      gzip_static on;
      expires     max;
      add_header  Cache-Control public;
      add_header  Last-Modified "";
      add_header  ETag "";
      # open_file_cache          max=1000 inactive=500s;
      # open_file_cache_valid    600s;
      # open_file_cache_errors   on;
      domain;
  }




       location / {



 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;



}
```

Comment: You are bypassing the `location /` block. You should try adding: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;` after the `if` block.

Comment: i have tried another method and still no success `location /widget/ {

if ($http_user_agent ~* (Android) ) { 
      set $test  A; 
    } 

if ($http_referer = "") { 
      set $test  "${test}B"; 
    } 

 if ($test = AB) { return 403; } 


try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;  }`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [If Is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/). To recap it: you shouldn't be using `if` inside `location`.

The `if` directive can be safely used only directly in the `server {}` context, if it's anywhere else then you're asking for troubles.

You'll have to write the conditional logic using `map` for the most part, and then use `if` within the safe context. Here's how.

First, define your `map`s within `http {}` (typically, in `nginx.conf`). The variable names are self-explanatory:

```
http {
    map $http_user_agent $is_android {
      default 0;
      ~Android 1;
    }

    map $http_referer $has_referer {
        default 0;
        ~.      1;
    }

    map $is_android:$has_referer $bad_client {
        default 0;
        1:0     1;
    }
    ...
}
```

Now we have the desired variable `$bad_client` available for use with `if` so you can apply restriction on bad clients like so:

```
server {
    if ($bad_client) {
        return 403; 
    }
    ...
}
```

To test:

```
curl -IL https://example.com/ -H "User-Agent: Android" # will get 403
curl -IL https://example.com/ -H "User-Agent: Android" -H "Referer: foo" # will get 200
```